# como hacer que un campo input type password muestre los 4 ultimos caracteres

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

quisiera hacer como hacen que los campos input con type password puedan mostrar los 4 caracteres, es muy comun en las areas donde pagas con tarjeta, que te colocas tu tarjeta y te muestra los ultimos caracteres o digitos

Comment: Previamente se ingresan los datos; del lado del servidor se procesa y solo se toman los últimos **n** caracteres y se muestran, esto por lo regular en pantalla de confirmación y realizado el proceso de compra. **No se hace antes y se hace en un teto que se muestra, no en el espacio de captura**

Comment: pero si lo he visto dura la captura de los datos,.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal, realicé algunas pruebas y llegué al siguiente resultado que me gustaría compartir contigo:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="show.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Numero de tarjeta:</p>
    <input type="text" maxlength="11" id="datos">
</body>
</html>
```

Se necesita establecer un encoding de utf-8 en la cabecera, después agregar la librería de [JQuery](https://jquery.com/download/) y limitar el máximo de caracteres del input a 11 al igual que agregarle un id.

El archivo show.js contiene jquery con el siguiente código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pActual = 0;
    var cardNumber = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'];
    var str = "";
    var cnt = 0;
    $("#datos").keyup(function(){
        pActual = $(this).val().length;
        var vActual = $(this).val();
        vActual = vActual.substr(pActual-1, pActual);
        if(pActual < 8){
            for(var i = 0; i <= cardNumber.length-1; i++){
                if(cardNumber[i] == vActual){
                    cnt = pActual;
                    if(cnt === pActual){
                        str += "•";
                        cnt += pActual;
                    }
                    $(this).val(str);
                }
            }
        }
        if($(this).val().length != cnt){
           str = str.substr(0, pActual);
           }
    });
});
```

Se lee de la siguiente manera:

1.-Cuando termine de cargar todo el html ejecutar una función

2.- Dentro de la función declarar 4 variables:

- pActual: Contiene el largo de los caracteres ingresados en el input.
- cardNumber: Arreglo que contiene números que ocultará.
- str: String que reemplazará el texto.
- cnt: contador que verifica si se eliminó un carácter.

3.- En el selector con el id 'datos' ejecutar una función cada vez que se presione y suelte una tecla.

4.- Establece pActual como el largo actual de los caracteres dentro del input.

5.- Se crea una variable llamada vActual que contiene el ultimo caracter ingresado.

6.- Si el largo de los caracteres en el input es menor a 8 entonces:

- Itera el numero de veces de largo del arreglo menos 1 (teniendo en cuenta que se empieza a contar desde 0).
- Si el carácter actual es igual a cualquier numero del arreglo entonces:
- Se establece cnt como la cantidad actual del largo del input.
- Si cnt es igual al largo del input:
- Se le agrega a str un carácter especial (para ello el encoding del header en el html).
- A cnt se le agrega e iguala a la posiciónActual.

7.- Se muestra el string 'str' dentro del input

8.- Si el valor actual del input no es igual al contador del largo anterior 'cnt' entonces:

- 'str' es igual al sub string que muestra desde la posición 0 hasta la posición del nuevo largo del input.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: definitivamente me ayudo muchisisimo muchas gracias !!!